# gegen etwas austauschen or durch etwas austauschen

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure which form is correct in the following sentence.

> Ich beschloss, in das Geschäft zurückzugehen und das Tuch gegen ein schöneres auszutauschen.

Is the *gegen* correct or should it be *durch* instead?

Comment: Gehört habe ich da noch weit mehr Varianten. Statt "gegen" und "durch", kann man auch "für" sagen. Statt "austauschen" auch "tauschen" oder "eintauschen". Die Bedeutungsunterschiede sind zum Teil sehr subtil.

Comment: @bernd_k The only problem is that _für_ is not correct at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Meines Erachtens ist in der Bedeutung des oben genannten Beispiels bei *"austauschen"* wie bei *"tauschen"* die Präposition ***"gegen"*** die grammatikalisch richtigere Variante. Siehe hierzu auch folgende andere Beispiele:

> - einen verletzten Spieler gegen einen anderen austauschen ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/austauschen))
> - man kann ein Adverb gegen eine adverbiale Bestimmung austauschen ([DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=austauschen&view=1))
> - *"und sind in ihrem stand so benüget, dasz sie auch ihr leben, handel und wandel nicht gegen einem königreich austauschen wolten"* ([Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GA09187))
> - Er wurde in der 20. Spielminute gegen Kahn ausgetauscht.([The Free Dictionary](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/austauschen))

Zunehmend wird aber auch die Präposition ***"durch"*** in dieser Bedeutung eingesetzt, wohl weil man auch sagen würde

> um das Tuch **durch** ein schöneres zu **ersetzen**.

Im nächsten Beispiel

> Das Steuerungsmodul darf nur **durch** einen Fachmann ausgetauscht werden.

wird *durch* in der Bedeutung mittels, mithilfe<sup>[1](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/durch_hindurch_mittels_waehrend),[2](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,349919,00.html)</sup> eingesetzt, es wird also nicht das ausgetauschte Objekt näher beschrieben, sondern der Prozess des Austauschens.

Damit wird auch der Unterschied zur Verwendung der Präposition *"gegen"* deutlich, die hier einen gänzlich anderen Sinn ergäbe.

Comment: Fast: Im Beispiel "durch einen Fachmann" ist der Fachmann nicht *Hilfsmittel* sondern *Agent* des Austauschprozesses.

Comment: @elena: genau, es ist die "bewirkende Person" - ich habe hier noch versucht, die Zwiebelfisch-Eselsbrücke ("mittels") in einen knappen Satz einzubauen.

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct.

For me (native speaker) there is a small difference. If you say `tausche gegen` you emphasize, that you give something back (there is a swap of goods). With `tausche durch X aus` it's more important to get something.

`tausche gegen` is a bit more colloquial.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the prepositions of *austauschen* and *ersetzen* (both meaning "replace").

The following sentences are correct and mean the same:

> Ich beschloss, in das Geschäft zurückzugehen und das Tuch gegen ein schöneres auszutauschen.

> Ich beschloss, in das Geschäft zurückzugehen und das Tuch durch ein schöneres zu ersetzen.

When using *austauchen* with *durch* it refers to the agent of the action and simply means "replace by":

> Der CEO wurde durch den Aufsichtsrat gegen einen kompetenteren ausgetauscht.

> The CEO has been replaced with a more competent one by the board.